# sending pointer to string array function. Will not print out the array in the main function

Tags: arrays, function, reference

So i've looked around on this site but nothing seems to work. 
Im trying to pass an array pointer to a function, read lines of numbers as strings to the array from a text file, then return the array back to the main function. It prints fine in the GetFile method, but once its sent to the main it doesn't appear.

```
using namespace std;

void GetFile(string *asArray)
{  

ifstream myfile("MyResourceFolder/GolfScores.txt");
int arrayIndex = 0;
string line;
asArray[20];
if (myfile)
{
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile, line);
        asArray[arrayIndex] = line;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
}

int main()
{
string aArray[20];
string *p = aArray;
GetFile(p);
cout << aArray[2] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you neglected to increment your index inside the while loop, resulting in each line being assigned in turn to element 0 in the array, with the last assignment likely being an empty line.  Try this instead:

```
asArray[arrayIndex++] = line;
```